# I can't load a 3d model in libgdx

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, blender

I'm trying to load a 3d model in libgdx but it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: model.g3db
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.UBJsonReader.parse(UBJsonReader.java:56)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.loader.G3dModelLoader.parseModel(G3dModelLoader.java:65)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.loader.G3dModelLoader.loadModelData(G3dModelLoader.java:61)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:53)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.ModelLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:69)
at com.xploor.animation.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:41)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:149)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: model.g3db (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:151)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.UBJsonReader.parse(UBJsonReader.java:54)
... 7 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: The line with `Caused by: com.badlogic....: File not found: model.g3db` would be relevant. Is it meant to be in CWD? Relative to CWD? Does it use a full path? If you are sure it can find the file, also check material and image files.

Comment: I guess you used the fbx-converter tool in order to convert your model into g3db. You should convert your model into g3dj (json format) and take a look at its internals. You can use the fbx-converter like that: 
"fbx-conv-win32.exe -f -v myModel.fbx convertedModel.g3dj". More info: https://github.com/libgdx/fbx-conv